# After animation, button disappeared?

Tags: android, animation

I have a screen, where you can generate yourself a daily quote by pressing the "Generate" button, and when you click on the button, an animation will play, and you get to a another activity. The another activity named, "Szabaly" will give you a random text, and then you can press the back button, and you can get back to the activity, where you can press the "Generate" button.

The problem is, that I'm clicking on the "Generate" button, the animation playes, and I get to the "Szabaly" activity without any problem, but soon as I press the back button, I will not find my "Generate" button. It's get dissappeared. Maybe I have to reset somehow the animation(state?) ? And set it to the first frame? If you know what I mean...

I want to code my app, to know that as soon as I get to the activity where you can click on the generate button, reset the animation to the first frame, and be able to play it every time, when I get in to the activity and click on it.

Here's my code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomOut).duration(700)
                .withListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        input.setText(null);
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Szabaly.class);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
```

I used this library: [Android ViewAnimations](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/32)

Comment: Are you using fill after true ?

Comment: Where should I put? setFillAfter(true); ?

Comment: The "Techniques.ZoomOut" hide the view at the end of the animation,  so try to call "Techniques.ZoomIn"(the reverse of the first animation), in *onAnimationEnd()* or when you come back to the activity, to show again the view (your button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code, in this code you can also set fillAfter, duration, zooming value, repeat, and other parameter of animation in xml. you can also create other animation from xml in same way.

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.viewLL);
        Animation zoomOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                R.anim.zoom_out);

        // set animation in listener
        zoomOutAnimation .setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // copy all file before start animation

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                // move to next activity

            }
        });

        view .startAnimation(zoomOutAnimation );
```

anim/zoom_out.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="400"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

YOYO not support 'fillafter' property. for the you'r view showed again do something like this after animation end action :`YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomIn).duration(1).playOn(animated_view);`